# Is it possible to have multi line input with unix dialog inputbox

Tags: unix, dialog

I would like to take multiple lines of input with something like `inputbox` with the unix `dialog` utility:

```
dialog --title "Inputbox - Example" --backtitle "Title" --inputbox "Prompt for input" 16 50
```

Is this possible or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--editbox` with an empty file:

```sh
touch /tmp/empty
dialog --title "Editbox - Example" --backtitle "Title" --editbox /tmp/empty 16 50
```

Comment: I had to redirect the stderr to a file but aside from that this answer was correct:

FILENAME="/tmp/my_file.txt"
dialog --title "Editbox - Example" --backtitle "Title" --editbox $FILENAME 16 50 2>$FILENAME

Thank you.